# Join two conferences in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I want to join two conferences (confbridge).
Suppose there is a conference room c1 and then there is another conf room c2, now i want that participant of c1 can also join participants of c2 but the condition is that c1 participant don't have to leave their room.

How can I implement this using confbridge and asterisk?

Comment: So the last time I answered one of your ConfBridge questions, you un-marked it as an answer some time later when I didn't respond fast enough to your subsequent questions - some of which had nothing to do with the original query.  I think I'll pass on writing up a comprehensive answer for your questions - suffice to say that this is doable with the Originate application and Local channels.

Comment: I'm grateful to you for responding in the past, and for the answer on this post despite the misunderstanding that I unmarked the previous answer. I never realized that it happened and I apologize for the same. I have immediately marked your answer on my previous post.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an implementation here:
[Connecting two conferences on initial join](http://leifmadsen.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/connecting-two-conferences-on-initial-join-with-cleanup/)

Answer (score 2):

considering you have two conferences rooms named 1 and 2 then add to your extensions.conf:

```
[join-conference]
exten => s,1,ConfBridge(2)
exten => s,n,Hangup
exten => h,1,Hangip
```

and do it in shell:

```
asterisk -rx "channel originate local/s@join-conference application ConfBridge 1"
```

Basically you are making a call with two legs: one to conference 1 and another to conference 2. It is not a big deal and works perfectly. let me know if you cant understand something.

You can learn more here:
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+local+channels

Comment: I am really grateful, it worked perfectly. I have a small question :- Is there any equivalent command in AMI for this "channel originate local/s@join-conference application ConfBridge 1". I looked for some solutions but really did not find the correct answer. I once again thanks for your help.

Comment: The similar AMI command has the same name: originate. http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Originate

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your suggestions were really helpful. I was able to implement it with the help of your suggestions. Thank you so much.