# Streaming a bridged call from Asterisk To ShoutCast

Tags: asterisk, shoutcast

I'd like to broadcast an Asterisk agent's conversation to a ShoutCast server. As each queued caller gets through in turn to the agent, his current conversation with his current caller needs to be sent to a specific stream.

I can find lots of info on setting up Asterisk to receive a ShoutCast broadcast, and I can find some info on using Ices to send a MeetMe conference to ShoutCast. The latter is no good for me as I need the queueing system and as far as I can see there's no way to be in a queue and a conference at the same time. Any other information is eluding me.

Thanks.

[edit] - whilst I've said ShoutCast above, any broadcast server would do. Preferably one I can run locally.

[UPDATE] - 
This question is no longer relevant to my particular problem. This functionality is no longer required for my project and therefore I don't need an answer anymore. However, it received 2 up votes so I can only assume that some other people would like an answer. Not sure of the etiquette in this case but should I leave it open so someone else can answer for others to reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asterisk ices command [1] or install a parallel freeswitch server, bridge both servers and use freeswitch's mod_shout [3].

[EDIT]
To capture the conversation use a conference room and setup a new call using a Local channel to the conference and to a dialplan context where you can run the ices command. [4]

More... you can use freeswitch and asterisk together to solve this. Make a call to freeswitch from asterisk Instead the ices command.

REFERENCES

[1] http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Ices

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icecast

[3] http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_shout

[4] [Join two conferences in asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964508/join-two-conferences-in-asterisk/11980169#11980169)

Comment: Thanks for your response. As far as I can see I can't keep the caller in the Queue when doing it as they suggest in [1]. I need to keep people in the queue so the agent will continue to be fed. The installed base is Asterisk at the moment (I am looking at Freeswitch already but I'm trying to exhaust the Asterisk options first).